# Finding position of specific substring within string

Tags: string-manipulation, natural-language, linguistics

Is there a simple way of finding the position of a specific instance of a substring within a string? For instance, in the sentence "Bob bought his car at the car dealership". Something like `StringPosition` would give me the position of both instances of car, namely `{{16, 18}, {27, 29}}`, but what if I only wanted the first or the second instance of the word?

If I do a `StringPosition` on every word of the sentece, both instances of the word "car" would yield `{{16, 18}, {27, 29}}`, as opposed to `{16, 18}` for the first instance and `{27, 29}` for the second instance, which is not very useful.

This seems to be a recurrent theme for a lot of Mathematica's NLP functions when they are applied to text: The functions act on each word, without considering the context of the word within the text. Mathematica just gives you all possible answers for each word.

Comment: `StringPosition` can take a third integer argument to return the first `n` occurrences. It's not hard to find the positions for the first occurrences of all words: `sentence = "Bob bought his car at the car dealership";
words = DeleteDuplicates@TextWords@sentence;
AssociationThread[words -> Flatten[StringPosition[sentence, #, 1] & /@ words, 1]]` and the results: `{"Bob" -> {1, 3}, "bought" -> {5, 10}, "his" -> {12, 14}, 
 "car" -> {16, 18}, "at" -> {20, 21}, "the" -> {23, 25}, 
 "dealership" -> {31, 40}}`

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "_context of the word_" ? To get the nth match, you could just do `pos = StringPosition[sentence,"car"]` then `pos[[n]]` surely?

Comment: So I want to find the position of all specific instances of the word "car", not get rid of duplicates. The above result does not give the position of the second instance of the word "car". You could manually get the nth match in the above fashion, but that defeats the purpose of having a function do it.

Comment: I think I figured a way to do it. The `Sort` function comes in handy to do `DeleteDuplicates[
 Sort[Flatten[StringPosition[sentence, #] & /@ words, 1]]]`. This gives us the desired result `{{1, 3}, {5, 10}, {12, 14}, {16, 18}, {20, 21}, {23, 25}, {27, 
  29}, {31, 40}}`, where the position of each substring (i.e. word) within the string (i.e. sentence) is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringPosition[str, WordCharacter .., Overlaps -> False]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 3}, {5, 10}, {12, 14}, {16, 18}, {20, 21}, {23, 25}, {27, 29}, {31, 40}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`DeleteDuplicates[Sort[Flatten[StringPosition["Bob bought his car at the car dealership", #] & /@ TextWords@"Bob bought his car at the car dealership", 1]]]`
gives us
`{{1, 3}, {5, 10}, {12, 14}, {16, 18}, {20, 21}, {23, 25}, {27,  29}, {31, 40}}`